# Does Rocky Linux on GCE support OS patching through VM manger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details#rocky_linux), OS patching in GCE via VM Manager is supported. However, after going through the configuration steps, Rocky Linux VMs in the OS Patch Management dashboard do not show; OS distribution, OS version or Status.

I've gone through the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os) to manually configure VM manager and the [verification](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/vm-manager/verify-setup) checklist which looks fine.

I'm able to deploy Debian, Ubuntu and CentOS public images and after about 10 minutes they appear in the OS patch management dashboard with all the information missing from Rocky Linux instances.

Is Rocky Linux fully supported for OS patching in GCE? Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Support here, I was able to reproduce the reported behavior inside my environment and I got the same result.

I've logged [issuetracker.google.com/201106605](http://issuetracker.google.com/201106605)  for tracking purposes.

You can visit the link and track the report progress.

Edited

Clarification: Patch Compliance is not supported but Patch Job and Patch Deployment should work as long as the OSConfigAgent is running.

Comment: We currently don't support the Patch Compliance feature for Rocky Linux so it's expected to see "no data" for the VM on the dashboard. A request to update our public documentations to mention this restriction was created.